# Why doesn't ParallelTable work on this very simple example?

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, warning-messages

For some reason, I'd like to use `ParallelTable` with a variable number of iterators.

- `Table[a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}]` works fine:

> *Output:* `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

- `ParallelTable[a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}]` returns an error:

> *Output:*
> ParallelTable::nopar1: ParallelTable[ci[1],{ci[1],0,10}] cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation. >>
>
> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

---

I am also interested in workarounds to use `ParallelTable` and a variable number of indices (typically: `ParallelTable[f[Table[a[i],{i,1,n}]],Table[a[j],{j,1,n}]]` where `f` is a function of a list with variable size).

Comment: It appears `ParallelTable[a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}]` not working with variable like `a[1]`, since `ParallelTable[f[i], {i, 0, 10}]` does work. `ParallelTable[f[Table[a[i],{i,1,n}]],Table[a[j],{j,1,n}]] does not make sense.

Comment: @kattern: Yes, that's my question: why does it work with `Table` but not with `ParallelTable`.

`With[{iter = Sequence @@ Table[{a[j],-1, n}, {j, 1, n}]}, 
 Table[f[Table[a[i], {i, 1, n}]], iter]]` if you prefer...

Comment: Still do not understand, can you please write an executable `Table` version of what you what?

Comment: @kattern Try this standalone code (which works): `With[{iter = Sequence @@ Table[{gag[j], -1, 1}, {j, 1, 3}]}, 
 Table[f[Table[gag[i], {i, 1, 3}]], iter]]!`. How can I make it work with `ParallelTable`instead of `Table`?

Comment: @kattern: Well... changing Table to ParallelTable works in this case. I still don't get it, why does `ParallelTable[a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}]`not work?

Comment: Yes, quite strange. Maybe you can substitute the variable like `ReleaseHold[Hold[ParallelTable[a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}]] /. a[1] -> i]` first. Let wait to see whether there is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) we can see that the evaluation of `ParallelTable[a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}]` becomes:

```
Parallel`Combine`Private`parallelIterateE[
  ParallelTable, Table, Join, Identity, a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}, {Automatic, "Global`"}
]
```

Further using `PrintDefinitions` in the GeneralUtilities package lets us peek behind the curtain:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions @ Parallel`Combine`Private`parallelIterateE
```

We see definitions specifically wanting a Symbol:

```
Parallel`Combine`Private`parallelIterateE[orig_, iter_, comb_, f_, 
  expr_, {i_Symbol, vals_List}, others___, {meth_, dist_, ___}] := . . .

Parallel`Combine`Private`parallelIterateE[orig_, iter_, comb_, f_, expr_, 
  it : {i_Symbol, w0_ : 1, w1_, dw_ : 1}, others___, {meth_, dist_, ___}] := . . .
```

If in each of these we replace `i_Symbol` with `i_Symbol | i : _Symbol[___]` and evaluate the cells we find that the problem is resolved:

```
ParallelTable[a[1], {a[1], 0, 10}]    (* no error message *)
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

In light of this I think it was an accident to restrict the iterators to bare Symbols, and I propose tagging this as a bug.

Comment: This is definitely an unwanted feature, as generating arbitrary-dimensional iterators and other such variables is often done with constructs like `c /@ Range[dim]`, which is much less cumbersome than working with lists of `Symbol[...]`, `Unique[]`, and such.

Comment: Very enlightening, thank you. I don't know how to report a bug.

Comment: @anderstood You're welcome.  I think under the **Help** menu you should find an item **Give Feedback...** that can be used to report bugs, among other things.  Or try emailing `support@wolfram.com`.

Comment: I sent them a message with Give Feedback. They answered today: _I have filed a report with our developers on this issue with ParallelTable.  This may allow them to address it in a future version of Mathematica._

Comment: @anderstood Have you heard back from them on this one? The original code works just fine on v10.4.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: No. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to just be a limitation of `ParallelTable`, can't comment whether that has a deeper reason due to parallelism or is just a simple oversight. I think it was not possible to use expressions like `a[i]` as e.g. iterators in older versions but in newer version that has been added as a feature to many functions, but obviously not `ParallelTable` (as of 10.0.2, still doesn't work in 10.1.0). That is somewhat inconsistent, and it *might* work with future versions, but for the moment you'd have to use a workaround as Kattern has suggested and use explicit symbols instead of the `a[i]` like e.g.:

```
asym[i_Integer] := Symbol["a" <> ToString[i]];
With[{
    iter = Sequence @@ Table[{asym[j], -1, 1}, {j, 1, 3}]
  },
  ParallelTable[$KernelID -> f[Table[asym[i], {i, 1, 3}]], iter]
]
```

alternatives to create symbol names would include:

```
asym[i_Integer] := asym[i] = Module[{a}, a];
asym[i_Integer] := asym[i] = Unique["a"];
```

each has there advantages and disadvantages, a common problem is that you have to manually cleanup as they create a bunch of symbols instead of just one as your original approach...